# How can I fix these Errors with Drupal 7 to Drupal 8 Migration

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-8

I have a client that needs/wants to upgrade their Drupal 7 site to Drupal 8. The site has over 50,000 articles, and most of the content was generated using the original "article" node/content type...but that original node has been customized to include a few more fields. The client wants me to create another custom content type for a new site feature, but I'd prefer to get the site upgraded to Drupal 8 before I begin work on the new features so I don't have to go through even more migration hassles in the future.

I have read through all the Drupal 6/7 to 8 Migration docs starting with this page: https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/upgrade/upgrading-from-drupal-6-or-7-to-drupal-8

I have tried to use the migration tools as per this write up with both the webui version, and the drush version. Both methods appear to use the same migration code, as both methods generate the same errors (see below):

First, here's what "drush migrate-status" gives us:

```
serverpilot@XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:~/apps/therooster-d8/public$ drush migrate-status
 Group: Import from Drupal 7 (migrate_drupal_7)  Status  Total  Imported  Unprocessed  Last imported
 upgrade_action_settings                         Idle    0      0         0
 upgrade_block_content_type                      Idle    1      0         1
 upgrade_d7_action                               Idle    15     0         15
 upgrade_d7_aggregator_settings                  Idle    0      0         0
 upgrade_d7_dblog_settings                       Idle    1      0         1
 upgrade_d7_file_private                         Idle    0      0         0
 upgrade_d7_filter_settings                      Idle    1      0         1
 upgrade_d7_global_theme_settings                Idle    1      0         1
 upgrade_d7_image_settings                       Idle    0      0         0
 upgrade_d7_image_styles                         Idle    13     0         13
 upgrade_d7_node_settings                        Idle    1      0         1
 upgrade_d7_search_settings                      Idle    0      0         0
 upgrade_d7_system_authorize                     Idle    0      0         0
 upgrade_d7_system_cron                          Idle    0      0         0
 upgrade_d7_system_date                          Idle    1      0         1
 upgrade_d7_system_file                          Idle    1      0         1
 upgrade_d7_system_mail                          Idle    0      0         0
 upgrade_d7_system_performance                   Idle    1      0         1
 upgrade_d7_theme_settings                       Idle    2      0         2
 upgrade_d7_tracker_settings                     Idle    0      0         0
 upgrade_d7_url_alias                            Idle    10890  0         10890
 upgrade_d7_user_flood                           Idle    0      0         0
 upgrade_d7_user_mail                            Idle    1      0         1
 upgrade_file_settings                           Idle    0      0         0
 upgrade_menu_settings                           Idle    0      0         0
 upgrade_search_page                             Idle    0      0         0
 upgrade_statistics_settings                     Idle    1      0         1
 upgrade_system_image                            Idle    1      0         1
 upgrade_system_image_gd                         Idle    1      0         1
 upgrade_system_logging                          Idle    1      0         1
 upgrade_system_maintenance                      Idle    0      0         0
 upgrade_system_rss                              Idle    0      0         0
 upgrade_system_site                             Idle    1      0         1
 upgrade_taxonomy_settings                       Idle    0      0         0
 upgrade_text_settings                           Idle    0      0         0
 upgrade_update_settings                         Idle    1      0         1
 upgrade_block_content_body_field                Idle    1      0         1
 upgrade_block_content_entity_display            Idle    1      0         1
 upgrade_block_content_entity_form_display       Idle    1      0         1
 upgrade_d7_filter_format                        Idle    5      0         5
 upgrade_d7_custom_block                         Idle    10     0         10
 upgrade_d7_user_role                            Idle    6      0         6
 upgrade_d7_block                                Idle    345    0         345
 upgrade_d7_field                                Idle    46     0         46
 upgrade_d7_node_type                            Idle    10     0         10
 upgrade_d7_comment_type                         Idle    10     0         10
 upgrade_d7_taxonomy_vocabulary                  Idle    3      0         3
 upgrade_d7_field_instance                       Idle    64     0         64
 upgrade_d7_file                                 Idle    50826  0         50826
 upgrade_user_picture_field                      Idle    1      0         1
 upgrade_user_picture_field_instance             Idle    1      0         1
 upgrade_user_picture_entity_display             Idle    1      0         1
 upgrade_user_picture_entity_form_display        Idle    1      0         1
 upgrade_d7_user                                 Idle    107    0         107
 upgrade_d7_comment_field                        Idle    10     0         10
 upgrade_d7_comment_field_instance               Idle    10     0         10
 upgrade_d7_node_ad                              Idle    204    0         204
 upgrade_d7_node_article                         Idle    9933   0         9933
 upgrade_d7_node_background_ad                   Idle    1      0         1
 upgrade_d7_node_establishment                   Idle    391    0         391
 upgrade_d7_node_green_guide                     Idle    6      0         6
 upgrade_d7_node_happy_hour                      Idle    176    0         176
 upgrade_d7_node_homepage_config                 Idle    2      0         2
 upgrade_d7_node_page                            Idle    7      0         7
 upgrade_d7_node_sidebar_config                  Idle    1      0         1
 upgrade_d7_node_webform                         Idle    1      0         1
 upgrade_d7_comment                              Idle    0      0         0
 upgrade_d7_comment_entity_display               Idle    10     0         10
 upgrade_d7_comment_entity_form_display          Idle    10     0         10
 upgrade_d7_comment_entity_form_display_subject  Idle    10     0         10
 upgrade_d7_view_modes                           Idle    5      0         5
 upgrade_d7_field_formatter_settings             Idle    97     0         97
 upgrade_d7_field_instance_widget_settings       Idle    64     0         64
 upgrade_d7_google_analytics_settings            Idle    1      0         1
 upgrade_d7_google_analytics_user_settings       Idle    107    0         107
 upgrade_d7_menu                                 Idle    7      0         7
 upgrade_d7_menu_links                           Idle    88     0         88
 upgrade_d7_node_revision_ad                     Idle    0      0         0
 upgrade_d7_node_revision_article                Idle    0      0         0
 upgrade_d7_node_revision_background_ad          Idle    0      0         0
 upgrade_d7_node_revision_establishment          Idle    0      0         0
 upgrade_d7_node_revision_green_guide            Idle    0      0         0
 upgrade_d7_node_revision_happy_hour             Idle    0      0         0
 upgrade_d7_node_revision_homepage_config        Idle    0      0         0
 upgrade_d7_node_revision_page                   Idle    0      0         0
 upgrade_d7_node_revision_sidebar_config         Idle    0      0         0
 upgrade_d7_node_revision_webform                Idle    0      0         0
 upgrade_d7_node_title_label                     Idle    10     0         10
 upgrade_d7_shortcut_set                         Idle    1      0         1
 upgrade_d7_shortcut                             Idle    4      0         4
 upgrade_d7_shortcut_set_users                   Idle    0      0         0
 upgrade_d7_taxonomy_term_category               Idle    56     0         56
 upgrade_d7_taxonomy_term_tags                   Idle    0      0         0
 upgrade_d7_taxonomy_term_vicinity               Idle    12     0         12
 Group: Beer Imports (beer)                      Status  Total  Imported  Unprocessed  Last imported
 beer_term                                       Idle    3      0         3
 beer_user                                       Idle    4      0         4
 beer_node                                       Idle    3      0         3
 beer_comment                                    Idle    5      0         5
 Group: Wine Imports (wine)                      Status  Total  Imported  Unprocessed  Last imported
 weather_soap                                    Idle    50     0         50
 wine_role_json                                  Idle    2      0         2
 wine_role_xml                                   Idle    2      0         2
 wine_terms                                      Idle    23     0         23
 wine_variety_multi_xml                          Idle    4      0         4
 Group: Default (default)                        Status  Total  Imported  Unprocessed  Last imported
 block_content_type                              Idle    1      1         0
 block_content_body_field                        Idle    1      1         0
 block_content_entity_display                    Idle    1      1         0
 block_content_entity_form_display               Idle    1      1         0
 user_picture_field                              Idle    1      0         1
 d6_upload_field                                 Idle    1      0         1
```

And this is what happens when I execute "drush migrate-import --all":

```
serverpilot@XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:~/apps/therooster-d8/public$ drush migrate-import --all
    Processed 1 item (1 created, 0 updated, 0 failed, 0 ignored) - done with 'upgrade_action_settings'           [status]
    Processed 1 item (1 created, 0 updated, 0 failed, 0 ignored) - done with 'upgrade_block_content_type'        [status]
    The "pathauto_node_update_action" plugin does not exist.                                                     [error]
    (/srv/users/serverpilot/apps/therooster-d8/public/core/lib/Drupal/Component/Plugin/Discovery/DiscoveryTrait.php:52)
    The "pathauto_taxonomy_term_update_action" plugin does not exist.                                            [error]
    (/srv/users/serverpilot/apps/therooster-d8/public/core/lib/Drupal/Component/Plugin/Discovery/DiscoveryTrait.php:52)
    The "pathauto_user_update_action" plugin does not exist.                                                     [error]
    (/srv/users/serverpilot/apps/therooster-d8/public/core/lib/Drupal/Component/Plugin/Discovery/DiscoveryTrait.php:52)
    Processed 15 items (11 created, 0 updated, 3 failed, 1 ignored) - done with 'upgrade_d7_action'              [status]
    upgrade_d7_action Migration - 3 failed.                                                                      [error]
    Processed 1 item (1 created, 0 updated, 0 failed, 0 ignored) - done with 'upgrade_d7_aggregator_settings'    [status]
    Processed 1 item (1 created, 0 updated, 0 failed, 0 ignored) - done with 'upgrade_d7_dblog_settings'         [status]
    Processed 0 items (0 created, 0 updated, 0 failed, 0 ignored) - done with 'upgrade_d7_file_private'          [status]
    Processed 1 item (1 created, 0 updated, 0 failed, 0 ignored) - done with 'upgrade_d7_filter_settings'        [status]
    Processed 1 item (1 created, 0 updated, 0 failed, 0 ignored) - done with 'upgrade_d7_global_theme_settings'  [status]
    Processed 1 item (1 created, 0 updated, 0 failed, 0 ignored) - done with 'upgrade_d7_image_settings'         [status]
    Processed 13 items (13 created, 0 updated, 0 failed, 0 ignored) - done with 'upgrade_d7_image_styles'        [status]
    Processed 1 item (1 created, 0 updated, 0 failed, 0 ignored) - done with 'upgrade_d7_node_settings'          [status]
    Processed 1 item (0 created, 0 updated, 0 failed, 1 ignored) - done with 'upgrade_d7_search_settings'        [status]
    Processed 1 item (1 created, 0 updated, 0 failed, 0 ignored) - done with 'upgrade_d7_system_authorize'       [status]
    Processed 1 item (1 created, 0 updated, 0 failed, 0 ignored) - done with 'upgrade_d7_system_cron'            [status]
    Processed 1 item (1 created, 0 updated, 0 failed, 0 ignored) - done with 'upgrade_d7_system_date'            [status]
    Processed 1 item (0 created, 0 updated, 0 failed, 1 ignored) - done with 'upgrade_d7_system_file'            [status]
    Processed 1 item (0 created, 0 updated, 0 failed, 1 ignored) - done with 'upgrade_d7_system_mail'            [status]
    Processed 1 item (1 created, 0 updated, 0 failed, 0 ignored) - done with 'upgrade_d7_system_performance'     [status]
    Processed 0 items (0 created, 0 updated, 0 failed, 0 ignored) - done with 'upgrade_d7_theme_settings'        [status]
    Processed 1 item (1 created, 0 updated, 0 failed, 0 ignored) - done with 'upgrade_d7_tracker_settings'       [status]
    Processed 10890 items (10890 created, 0 updated, 0 failed, 0 ignored) - done with 'upgrade_d7_url_alias'     [status]
    Processed 1 item (1 created, 0 updated, 0 failed, 0 ignored) - done with 'upgrade_d7_user_flood'             [status]
    Processed 1 item (1 created, 0 updated, 0 failed, 0 ignored) - done with 'upgrade_d7_user_mail'              [status]
    Processed 1 item (1 created, 0 updated, 0 failed, 0 ignored) - done with 'upgrade_file_settings'             [status]
    Processed 1 item (1 created, 0 updated, 0 failed, 0 ignored) - done with 'upgrade_menu_settings'             [status]
    Processed 1 item (1 created, 0 updated, 0 failed, 0 ignored) - done with 'upgrade_search_page'               [status]
    Processed 1 item (1 created, 0 updated, 0 failed, 0 ignored) - done with 'upgrade_statistics_settings'       [status]
    Processed 1 item (1 created, 0 updated, 0 failed, 0 ignored) - done with 'upgrade_system_image'              [status]
    Processed 1 item (1 created, 0 updated, 0 failed, 0 ignored) - done with 'upgrade_system_image_gd'           [status]
    Processed 1 item (1 created, 0 updated, 0 failed, 0 ignored) - done with 'upgrade_system_logging'            [status]
    Processed 1 item (1 created, 0 updated, 0 failed, 0 ignored) - done with 'upgrade_system_maintenance'        [status]
    Processed 1 item (1 created, 0 updated, 0 failed, 0 ignored) - done with 'upgrade_system_rss'                [status]
    Processed 1 item (1 created, 0 updated, 0 failed, 0 ignored) - done with 'upgrade_system_site'               [status]
    Processed 1 item (1 created, 0 updated, 0 failed, 0 ignored) - done with 'upgrade_taxonomy_settings'         [status]
    Processed 1 item (1 created, 0 updated, 0 failed, 0 ignored) - done with 'upgrade_text_settings'             [status]
    Processed 1 item (1 created, 0 updated, 0 failed, 0 ignored) - done with 'upgrade_update_settings'           [status]
    Processed 1 item (1 created, 0 updated, 0 failed, 0 ignored) - done with 'upgrade_block_content_body_field'  [status]
    Processed 1 item (1 created, 0 updated, 0 failed, 0 ignored) - done with                                     [status]
    'upgrade_block_content_entity_display'
    Processed 1 item (1 created, 0 updated, 0 failed, 0 ignored) - done with                                     [status]
    'upgrade_block_content_entity_form_display'
    Missing filter plugin: filter_null.                                                                          [error]
    Processed 5 items (5 created, 0 updated, 0 failed, 0 ignored) - done with 'upgrade_d7_filter_format'         [status]
    Processed 10 items (10 created, 0 updated, 0 failed, 0 ignored) - done with 'upgrade_d7_custom_block'        [status]
    Processed 6 items (6 created, 0 updated, 0 failed, 0 ignored) - done with 'upgrade_d7_user_role'             [status]
    Processed 345 items (38 created, 0 updated, 0 failed, 307 ignored) - done with 'upgrade_d7_block'            [status]
    Attempt to create a field storage field_establishment with no type.                                          [error]
    (/srv/users/serverpilot/apps/therooster-d8/public/core/modules/field/src/Entity/FieldStorageConfig.php:252)
    Attempt to create a field storage field_daily_menu with no type.                                             [error]
    (/srv/users/serverpilot/apps/therooster-d8/public/core/modules/field/src/Entity/FieldStorageConfig.php:252)
    Attempt to create a field storage field_articles with no type.                                               [error]
    (/srv/users/serverpilot/apps/therooster-d8/public/core/modules/field/src/Entity/FieldStorageConfig.php:252)
    Attempt to create a field storage field_articles with no type.                                               [error]
    (/srv/users/serverpilot/apps/therooster-d8/public/core/modules/field/src/Entity/FieldStorageConfig.php:252)
    Attempt to create a field storage field_trending_articles with no type.                                      [error]
    (/srv/users/serverpilot/apps/therooster-d8/public/core/modules/field/src/Entity/FieldStorageConfig.php:252)
    Processed 46 items (41 created, 0 updated, 5 failed, 0 ignored) - done with 'upgrade_d7_field'               [status]
    upgrade_d7_field Migration - 5 failed.                                                                       [error]
    Processed 10 items (10 created, 0 updated, 0 failed, 0 ignored) - done with 'upgrade_d7_node_type'           [status]
    Processed 10 items (10 created, 0 updated, 0 failed, 0 ignored) - done with 'upgrade_d7_comment_type'        [status]
    Processed 3 items (3 created, 0 updated, 0 failed, 0 ignored) - done with 'upgrade_d7_taxonomy_vocabulary'   [status]
    Attempt to create a field field_establishment that does not exist on entity type node.                       [error]
    (/srv/users/serverpilot/apps/therooster-d8/public/core/modules/field/src/Entity/FieldConfig.php:293)
    Attempt to create a field field_daily_menu that does not exist on entity type node.                          [error]
    (/srv/users/serverpilot/apps/therooster-d8/public/core/modules/field/src/Entity/FieldConfig.php:293)
    Attempt to create a field field_articles that does not exist on entity type node.                            [error]
    (/srv/users/serverpilot/apps/therooster-d8/public/core/modules/field/src/Entity/FieldConfig.php:293)
    Attempt to create a field field_articles that does not exist on entity type node.                            [error]
    (/srv/users/serverpilot/apps/therooster-d8/public/core/modules/field/src/Entity/FieldConfig.php:293)
    Attempt to create a field field_articles that does not exist on entity type taxonomy_term.                   [error]
    (/srv/users/serverpilot/apps/therooster-d8/public/core/modules/field/src/Entity/FieldConfig.php:293)
    Attempt to create a field field_trending_articles that does not exist on entity type node.                   [error]
    (/srv/users/serverpilot/apps/therooster-d8/public/core/modules/field/src/Entity/FieldConfig.php:293)
    Processed 64 items (58 created, 0 updated, 6 failed, 0 ignored) - done with 'upgrade_d7_field_instance'      [status]
    upgrade_d7_field_instance Migration - 6 failed.                                                              [error]
    Processed 50826 items (50817 created, 0 updated, 9 failed, 0 ignored) - done with 'upgrade_d7_file'          [status]
    upgrade_d7_file Migration - 9 failed.                                                                        [error]
    Processed 1 item (1 created, 0 updated, 0 failed, 0 ignored) - done with 'upgrade_user_picture_field'        [status]
    Processed 1 item (1 created, 0 updated, 0 failed, 0 ignored) - done with                                     [status]
    'upgrade_user_picture_field_instance'
    Processed 1 item (1 created, 0 updated, 0 failed, 0 ignored) - done with                                     [status]
    'upgrade_user_picture_entity_display'
    Processed 1 item (1 created, 0 updated, 0 failed, 0 ignored) - done with                                     [status]
    'upgrade_user_picture_entity_form_display'
    InvalidArgumentException: Passed variable is not an array or object in                                       [error]
    /srv/users/serverpilot/apps/therooster-d8/public/core/modules/migrate/src/Plugin/migrate/process/Flatten.php:52
    Stack trace:
    #0
    /srv/users/serverpilot/apps/therooster-d8/public/core/modules/migrate/src/Plugin/migrate/process/Flatten.php(52):
    ArrayIterator->__construct(NULL)
    #1 /srv/users/serverpilot/apps/therooster-d8/public/core/modules/migrate/src/MigrateExecutable.php(380):
    Drupal\migrate\Plugin\migrate\process\Flatten->transform(NULL,
    Object(Drupal\migrate_tools\MigrateExecutable), Object(Drupal\migrate\Row), 'permissions')
    #2
    /srv/users/serverpilot/apps/therooster-d8/public/core/modules/migrate/src/Plugin/migrate/process/MigrationLookup.php(223):
    Drupal\migrate\MigrateExecutable->processRow(Object(Drupal\migrate\Row), Array)
    #3 /srv/users/serverpilot/apps/therooster-d8/public/core/modules/migrate/src/MigrateExecutable.php(366):
    Drupal\migrate\Plugin\migrate\process\MigrationLookup->transform(Array,
    Object(Drupal\migrate_tools\MigrateExecutable), Object(Drupal\migrate\Row), 'roles')
    #4 /srv/users/serverpilot/apps/therooster-d8/public/core/modules/migrate/src/MigrateExecutable.php(203):
    Drupal\migrate\MigrateExecutable->processRow(Object(Drupal\migrate\Row))
    #5 /srv/users/serverpilot/apps/therooster-d8/vendor/drush/drush/includes/drush.inc(721):
    Drupal\migrate\MigrateExecutable->import()
    #6 /srv/users/serverpilot/apps/therooster-d8/vendor/drush/drush/includes/drush.inc(712):
    drush_call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
    #7
    /srv/users/serverpilot/apps/therooster-d8/public/modules/contrib/migrate_tools/migrate_tools.drush.inc(303):
    drush_op(Array)
    #8 [internal function]: _drush_migrate_tools_execute_migration(Object(Drupal\user\Plugin\migrate\User),
    'upgrade_d7_user', Array)
    #9
    /srv/users/serverpilot/apps/therooster-d8/public/modules/contrib/migrate_tools/migrate_tools.drush.inc(267):
    array_walk(Array, '_drush_migrate_...', Array)
    #10 /srv/users/serverpilot/apps/therooster-d8/vendor/drush/drush/includes/command.inc(422):
    drush_migrate_tools_migrate_import()
    #11 /srv/users/serverpilot/apps/therooster-d8/vendor/drush/drush/includes/command.inc(231):
    _drush_invoke_hooks(Array, Array)
    #12 /srv/users/serverpilot/apps/therooster-d8/vendor/drush/drush/includes/command.inc(199): drush_command()
    #13 /srv/users/serverpilot/apps/therooster-d8/vendor/drush/drush/lib/Drush/Boot/BaseBoot.php(67):
    drush_dispatch(Array)
    #14 /srv/users/serverpilot/apps/therooster-d8/vendor/drush/drush/includes/preflight.inc(66):
    Drush\Boot\BaseBoot->bootstrap_and_dispatch()
    #15 /srv/users/serverpilot/apps/therooster-d8/vendor/drush/drush/drush.php(12): drush_main()
    #16 {main}
```

Basically, the nearly 10K articles don't migrate over. That's primarily what I need. I've tried matching and enabling all the modules that I could match from Drupal 7 to 8...but perhaps I'm missing something that a trained eye is able to see from the errors above? Your help is much appreciated. Thank you

Comment: With respect to the 10k articles, I take it you’re talking about “content”.  For that I would use the backup and migrate module (first’ modify the Article content type and fields in the news site ).

Comment: That's actually a good idea. I will try to import into the D8 site using backup_migrate module...and if that doesn't work directly, I'll create a blank D7 site, import into that (hopefully that works), and then perhaps an upgrade/migration to D8 will then be more successful. Thanks for the idea! I'll let you know how it goes.

Comment: Welcome to SO. If any of the answers took care of the original question, choose an answer (green button)

Comment: @Salah-1 I'm struggling to see how Backup and Migrate will help the OP upgrade from Drupal 7 to Drupal 8 but I'm all ears/eyes.

Comment: That’s referring to content migration and not configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest doing it gradually and in pieces not all as you indicated by the drush command.
By using drush, first do the configuration using the switch [drush.....  --configure-only]
This will create the needed configuration at the target site/dB including Articles.

You can also do everything except the problem portions by using the manifest file switch (see docs in that link above about the manifest file with drush).

**Update**:
Install the features module which integrates with drush and export /import the Articles content type.  Then attempt the content migration using backup and migrate.
**D7**: https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/contrib/features/features-drush

**D8**: https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/modules/features

Comment: The first section of my post is the result of the "configure-only" status. When performing the migration, all the "successful" parts of the migration do in fact migrate...but unfortunately the articles aren't part of that. I think I'm going to basically re-create the article content type in the new D8 site, then create one "article" node, then see how it all works in the database. Once I've figured that out, I'll probably use the migration tools inside MySQL Workbench and see if I can just populate the DB from the backend.

Comment: Updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

I don't enjoy being the bearer of bad news, but in my experience there are no one-click, automatic solutions that will upgrade and migrate from D7 to D8.

You'll end up with a far more stable product—and most likely save time and santity—if you rebuild the site in D8 and carry out a migration using the Migrate API.

Comment: I'm assuming that you mean the instructions found on this page?: https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/migrate-api/migrate-api-overview if so, I'll give it a good read...thanks for pointing me in the right direction.